# Let $(H,\mu,\nu,\Delta,\epsilon,R)$ be a braided bialgebra. Then the map ${}_{R}\lambda: H^* \rightarrow H$..

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(H,\mu,\nu,\Delta,\epsilon,R)$ be a braided bialgebra. Then the map ${}_{R}\lambda: H^* \rightarrow H$ defined by ${}_{R}\lambda(\alpha)=\sum_{i}\alpha(s_i)t_i$ is an algebra morphism.

Proof:

$${}_{R}\lambda(\alpha\beta)=\sum_i(\alpha\beta)(s_i)t_i=\sum_i(\alpha \otimes \beta)(\Delta(s_i))t_i=\sum_{i,j}\alpha(s_i)\beta(s_j)t_it_j={}_{R}\lambda(\alpha){}_{R}\lambda(\beta)$$

Can somebody explain the third equality to me? Why do we get a $t_j$ term to sum over? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this Proposition VIII.2.5 from Kassel? If so, the "extra $t_j$" after the third equality comes from an application of relation (2.5),
$$
\sum_{i,(s_i)} (s_i)'\otimes(s_i)''\otimes t_i = \sum_{i,j} s_i\otimes s_j\otimes t_i t_j\ .
$$
I think it implicitly goes something like this: first use the canonical isomorphism $H\cong k\otimes k\otimes H$ to write $(\alpha\otimes\beta)(\Delta(s_i)) t_i$ as $(\alpha\otimes\beta\otimes\mathrm{id}_H)(\Delta(s_i)\otimes t_i)$; then use (2.5) to rewrite $\sum_{i}\Delta(s_i)\otimes t_i$ as $\sum_{i,j} s_i\otimes s_j\otimes t_i t_j$; finally apply $\alpha\otimes\beta\otimes\mathrm{id}_H$ and identify $k\otimes k\otimes H$ back with $H$.